# Split selected value with _

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, material-ui, jinja2

I am using material css for my web page design. I am having one single select country list dropdown and the values

```
<select id="select_id" name="select_id" required>
  <option value="8">select1_1</option>
  <option value="15">select2_2</option>
</select>
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('select').formSelect();
 });
```

My select option are populating from a database which has an underscore in its value. I want to update the select option value at runtime on the client side and remove the underscore from options.

```
<select id="select_id" name="select_id" required>
  <option value="8">select1</option>
  <option value="15">select2</option>
</select>
```

Is there is any better way to update it using jQuery. Thanks for the help

Comment: *can't modify the `option`* - how exactly do you get the data from the DB? Do you need the original text/value anywhere?  If it's a table, change it to a view and adjust it there, easy and no terrible FOUC.

Comment: if you are using jinja2, why don't you show the code for jinja2 that's building this dropdown? I mean, what is the code doing right now that's showing how this is being generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While changing at the source is the better solution, you can update the *text* of an option using the `.text()` overload that [accepts a function](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function):

```js
$("select option").text((i, txt) => txt.replace(/_.*$/, ''))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_id" name="select_id" required>
  <option value="8">select1_1</option>
  <option value="15">select2_2</option>
</select>
```

---

> remove the underscore from options

the above matches your sample that removes both the underscore and what follows it, to remove just the underscore:

```
$("select option").text((i, txt) => txt.replace(/_/g, ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the original value as "value" prop of the `<option>` tag. For the option text the best way to handle it is to create a parser `parseOptionText(optionText: string): string`, in this way you have full control over the logic of the parsing and the code is easy to maintain.

As final result you should have:

```
<option value={originalValueFromDB}>parseOptionText(originalValueFromDB)</option>
```

And

```
const parseOptionText = (optionText: string): string => {
    return optionText.replace('_', '');
}
```

Comment: I am using Jinja 2 template. Can't modify the option.